# Uncaught ReferenceError:Calendar is not defined in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

i'm working on laravel project , and i'm trying to install the FullCalendar in my app at first it was working but now i got this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined

This is the view of the calendar :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  headerToolbar: {
    center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridFourDay' // buttons for switching between views
  },
  views: {
    timeGridFourDay: {
      type: 'timeGrid',
      duration: { days: 4 },
      buttonText: '4 day'
    }
  }
});
              console.log(new Date(info.event.start).toLocaleDateString());
                     calendar.render();
            @foreach($calendar->monday as $ja)
            calendar.addEvent({
                title:"{{$ja}}",
                daysOfWeek: [ '1' ]
            });
            @endforeach
            
            @foreach($calendar->tuesday as $ja)
            calendar.addEvent({
                title:"{{$ja}}",
                daysOfWeek: [ '2' ]
              });
            @endforeach
            @foreach($calendar->wednesday as $ja)
            calendar.addEvent({
                title:"{{$ja}}",
                daysOfWeek: [ '3' ]
            });
            @endforeach
            @foreach($calendar->thursday as $ja)
            calendar.addEvent({
                title:"{{$ja}}",
                daysOfWeek: [ '4' ]
            });
            @endforeach
            @foreach($calendar->friday as $ja)
            calendar.addEvent({
                title:"{{$ja}}",
                daysOfWeek: [ '5' ]
            });
            @endforeach
            @foreach($calendar->saturday as $ja)
            calendar.addEvent({
                title:"{{$ja}}",
                daysOfWeek: [ '6' ]
            });
            @endforeach
        }); 
      })
```

the links witch contains the fullcalendar :

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.0.0/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.0.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.0.0/main.css" rel='stylesheet' />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals). `new Calendar` should be `new FullCalendar.Calendar`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```